# What is the initial value of Embedding layer?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embedding

I am studying embedding for word representations. In many dnn libraries, they support embedding layer. And this is really nice tutorial.

[Word Embeddings: Encoding Lexical Semantics](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/word_embeddings_tutorial.html)

But I am not still sure how to calculate embed value. In below example, it outputs some value even before any trainings. Does it use some random weights? I realize a purpose of `Embedding(2, 5)`, but not sure its initial calculation. And I am no sure about how to learn weights of its Embedding too.

```
word_to_ix = {"hello": 0, "world": 1}
embeds = nn.Embedding(2, 5)  # 2 words in vocab, 5 dimensional embeddings
lookup_tensor = torch.LongTensor([word_to_ix["hello"]])
hello_embed = embeds(autograd.Variable(lookup_tensor))
print(hello_embed)
--------
Variable containing:
-2.9718  1.7070 -0.4305 -2.2820  0.5237
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x5]
```

I break down my thought to be sure. First of all, upper `Embedding(2, 5)` is a matrix of shape `(2, 5)`.

```
Embedding(2, 5) = 
 [[0.1,-0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1],
 [-0.2,0.1,0.8,0.2,0.3]] # initiated by some function, like random normal distribution
```

Then, `hello` is `[1, 0]`. Then `hello` representation is calculated by `[1, 0].dot(Embedding(2, 5)) = [0.1,-0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1]`. This is actually first row of the Embedding. Am I understanding right?

---

## Updates

I found a code of embedding which is exactly use normal distribution for its value. Yes, but it is just a default value, and we can set arbitrary weights for embedding layers.
https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/adba7b846d018b9dc7d19d52147ef53f5e555dc8/chainer/links/connection/embed_id.py#L58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You start off with random weights. I think it is more common to use a truncated normal distribution instead of the regular normal distribution. But, that probably doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Uniform distribution is also commom.

Answer (score 2):

`Initializations` define the way to set the initial `random weights` of layers. You can use any value to do it. But initial values affect `Word Embedding`. There are many approach for `Pre-trained Word Embedding` that they try to choose better initial values like [this](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W17-2338).